# Homebrew PHP appears not to be linked. - Valet

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.1, laravel-valet

I had a problem which appeared all of the sudden saying:
`Unable to determine linked PHP.` which I could not solve so I uninstalled valet, php and dependencies. Then I installed fresh `php7.1` but when I run `valet install` I get quiet slightly similar error: `Homebrew PHP appears not to be linked.`

Comment: @ValentinKnyazev there is plenty of topics about question you posted. It is not my case

Comment: Homebrew can't find the correct PHP version, have you linked them up properly? brew link php71

Comment: @WouterVanDamme thank you. That was it. I tried it dozen times before but it did not have effect, now it did :D It was never needed to link it explicitly

Comment: @Paul Well the answer with big green check icon does:)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Homebrew can't find the correct PHP version, have you linked them up properly?

`brew link php71`

Answer (score 38):

First, find the PHP version installed via.

```
brew list
```

In my case it was php@7.3, then

```
brew link php@7.3 --force --overwrite
```

and finally

```
valet install
```

:)

Answer (score 5):

brew link php@7.2 --force --overwrite

That will push this--

If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

I ran both independently then tried valet install (worked like a charm).

Answer (score 2):

```
brew install php@7.1
```

then link it

```
brew link php@7.1 --force --overwrite
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ brew unlink php && brew link --force php@7.1
```

Comment: Please, add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming here following a migration from Intel to M1 and having Valet not use the php cask from the /opt/ folder, this did the trick for me:

`echo "export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc`.